# Multiple Ajax Calls while one Ajax call is still running

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, simultaneous-calls

I got some progressbar Update Issues. What I like to do is, fire a ajax call which takes some time to complete and during the this call I'd like to fire ajax calls, set by an interval, to update my progressbar.

Since I could not find a solution and only found the Browser's restriction, which would match here. It's always max 2 calls active.

Still, my second call stays pending in Google Chrome,  untill my first (main) call finished.

EDIT: full jquery script

```
// update cars cache
$('#cars_cache_update_run').bind('click', function(){
    // remove button
    $(this).remove();

    // hide import widgets
    $('#products_import_widget').css('display', 'none');
    $('#vehicles_import_widget').css('display', 'none');
    $('#orders_import_widget').css('display', 'none');
    $('#test_data_widget').css('display', 'none');

    // show blind
    $('#cars_cache_update_info').css('display', 'none');
    $('#cars_cache_update_blind').css('display', 'inline');

    var carsUpdateInterval = setInterval(function() {
        getImportState('http://localhost/index.php/import/import_state/cache_update', 'cars_import_progressbar');
    }, 1000);
    // ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/index.php/import/cars_cache",
        async : true,
        success: function(data){
            $('#cars_cache_update_blind').css('display', 'none');
            $('#cars_cache_update_success').css('display', 'inline');
            clearInterval(carsUpdateInterval);

        },
        error: function(thrownError){
            $('#cars_cache_update_blind').css('display', 'none');
            $('#cars_cache_update_error').css('display', 'inline');
            $('#cars_cache_update_error_msg').html(thrownError);
        }
    });
});

function getImportState(url, id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);

            $.each(json, function(i, item) {
                var progressbar_value = json[i]['state'];
                $( "#"+id ).progressbar({
                    value: progressbar_value
                });
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Another funny thing, if I call the interval request by $.get I'll get a strange error..
Working with Codeignitor Framework.

```
GET http://localhost/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found) jquery.1.7.min.js:4
send jquery.1.7.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery.1.7.min.js:4
f.(anonymous function) jquery.1.7.min.js:4
(anonymous function)
```

Many Thanks for your help already, been trying for hours now.. Maybe I'm just a noob.. Haha.

rootless

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple ajax calls at same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150159/multiple-ajax-calls-at-same-time)

Comment: How are you handling this on the serverside, as often times there can be issues with only request per session etc. when doing multiple ajax calls to the same backend.

Comment: tried the encapsulate in an outer function, no success.

Comment: adneo: I'm just calling a controller/method in Codeigniter Framework.. Haven't thought about that. Do you know how to test or then increase the value of the requests per session?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call multiple ajax with intervals. Try something like this:

```
function updateProgress(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/index.php/import/import_state/cache_update",
        success: function(data){
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(json, function(i, item) {
                var progressbar_value = json[i]['state'];
                $( "#cars_import_progressbar" ).progressbar({
                    value: progressbar_value
                });
            });
            updateProgress(); // after success, call the same function again
        }
    });
}

updateProgress(); // start updateProgress
```

Hope it helps :]

Comment: i see what you meant now - i tried to put the updateProgressFile request before the actual updateFile request.
the result ended in one updateProgressFile request and after the updateFile call it hangs again on pending..