# jQuery-How to call multiple ajax calls in one ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my Javascript file I have multiple ajax calls, I would like to change all ajax calls to one ajax call. Here is my sample JS code.

```
var vpnPin = $.ajax({ 
  dataType: "json",
  url: "url",
  async: true,
  success: function(result) {}                     
});  //$.ajax() ends


var vpnDataPlan = $.ajax({ 
  dataType: "json",
  url: "url",
  async: true,
  success: function(result) {}  
});  //$.ajax() ends
```

How can we call multiple AJAX calls to one AJAX call?

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150159/multiple-ajax-calls-at-same-time

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. You can't just merge different AJAX calls without changing the server code to return multiple pieces of information.

Comment: On a hunch, maybe he wants to ask how to chain the calls to make sure call 2 happens after call 1.  But it doesn't read this way currently.

Comment: Also, most of the ajax params are blank or place-holders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible using promises concept in javascript. Read [promises and defered](http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics).

Using your above example it can be done like:

```
//assuming vpnPin and vpnDataPlan are the deferred object returned from $.ajax.
//As you have done in your example.

$.when(vpnPin, vpnDataPlan).done(function(){
    //work to do after the completion of both calls.
});
```

There are many more variations of this. **[RSVP](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js?utm_source=javascriptweekly)** implements the standard way of handling promises.

Comment: This answer is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

**Not possible in most cases**

Each ajax call involves the browser sending information to a server at a particular URL.

If you reduced the browser code from two ajax calls to one ajax call, the server would receive less information, the browser would not receive some information it is getting now, and/or the server would perform fewer operations.

If you control the server code, you might be able to change the server code to be able to do both operations in one step.  Only then could you change the browser code.