# Using Two jQuery Ajax Methods in Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can you please let me know how I can use two Ajax call in one script and avoid conflicts? For example, I have a script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'nearest.php',
         success: function( resp1 ){
          $("#div1").html(resp1);
         }
    });

      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'closettime.php',
         success: function( resp2 ){
         $("#div2").html(resp2);
         }
    });   
</script>
```

Can you please let me know how I can use both methods in the script? Thanks.

Comment: You should explain why they conflict.

Comment: There's no conflicts by doing what you do. Why do you think so? Secondly, an Ajax request is made to a single resource (Url).

Comment: well, I am not getting any result! is it possible to use the $.ajax() two times? any way?

Comment: Well if that is the actual code, you have a syntax error.

Comment: install firebug and monitor the ajax call

Comment: @Behseini there's no problem making 2 requests the way you are doing. You must have a different problem. Did you check the Console output using Google Developer Tools (Hit F12 in Google Chrome and click on the console tab)?

Comment: this should help You

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150159/multiple-ajax-calls-at-same-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just close `DOM ready` with `})`; at the bottom of your script block and you're all set:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'nearest.php',
         success: function( resp1 ){
          $("#div1").html(resp1);
         }
    });

      $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'closettime.php',
         success: function( resp2 ){
         $("#div2").html(resp2);
         }
    }); 
});// <------ YOU'RE MISSING THIS
```

The requests should work fine. And since you're not posting any data to the URLs I might suggest that you use `type:'GET'`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want to use the $.when method http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

[jQuery.when understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280699/jquery-when-understanding)

Comment: Try to provide more detail in your answer instead of just posting multiple links

Answer (score -2):

possibly put one in the callback of the other, I don't understand the problem off the top my head. But if div2 is inside div 1 or something you can control the order in that fashion