# Allow clients to run multiple simultaneous PHP requests

Tags: php, mamp

How can I allow one client to run multiple simultaneous PHP requests?

I've been googling a lot. I tried session_write_close() at the top of my PHP script.

I tried to edit the httpd.conf but nothing bites.

What should I do?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do??

Comment: Have you tried jQuery? Is there a particular reason you want to close the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking to perform an asynchronous request (AJAX), and jQuery is useful for this.

Check out the `jQuery.ajax()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

There are plenty of tutorials online to help you get started with [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/), and this SO post discusses how to make [Multiple ajax calls at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150159/multiple-ajax-calls-at-same-time).

**Edit**:
Since you clarified in your comments that:

- You are already using jQuery but are running into challenges with the server allowing multiple simultaneous connections.
- You also indicated that you already tried adding missing values to *httpd.conf* and restarted your Apache server.

If adding missing settings to *httpd.conf* doesn't work and you have also checked that they are not already included in *httpd.conf* through, perhaps, *httpd-mpm.conf*.

Your OP indicated that you have tried resolving the session conflicts using `session_write_close()`, but perhaps the additional requests are getting discarded/ignored rather than queued.
You could try replacing the default file-based session handler with one that calls a database, which should eliminate the problem of conflicts that arise when two processes attempt to read the same session file at the same time. This article ([Saving PHP's Session data to a database](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/session-handler.html)) seems to cover it pretty well.

Comment: I just want to configure my Apache to allow multiple connection per client.

Comment: I already use ajax, but it doesn't help because Apache doesn't allow multiple simultaneous connections for a client.

Comment: Have you reviewed this post regarding "Simultaneous Requests to PHP Script"?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1430890/3424147

Comment: yes I did, but I cant find where to edit these options for apache. I'm looking in httpd.conf but the options aren't there, so I tried to add them, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you re-start your Apache server after saving the changes?

Comment: Yes, I did. I restarted MAMP (which also restarts Apache).

Comment: Is your httpd.conf including *httpd-mpm.conf* ? Those settings may exist there instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70967/discussion-between-cragmonkey-and-user1878980).

Comment: It works if I run the script simultaneously from different browsers (or different browser sessions) which solves my issue for now. Big thanks @Cragmonkey