# PHP executing ajax calls sequentially

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is driving me nuts for a while now. I have an `ajax` call like so:

```
function update()
{
    $.get("update.php", function(data)
    {
        $("#output-progress").html(data);
    });
}
```

And I call it like so:

```
window.setInterval(function()
    {
        update();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Then I have another calc function which is also called:

```
function calc()
{
    $.get("calc.php", function(data)
    {
        //whole bunch of lines to re-render page
    });
}
```

So the idea is that while `calc()` is running, the `update()` will periodically update a div on the progress.

However what is happening is that if I open the console and check the calls to `update()` is triggered every 5 seconds, but they just stall and they complete only after the `calc()` has returned. I first thought this was a `browser/jQuery` issue, but if I log both the functions into separate log files in PHP then the `update()` gets logged only after the `calc()` finishes!

Im not sure what is going on here, any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10152046/2518525) is worth a read.

Comment: This sounds like it totally depends upon your PHP scripts and infrastructure.  This is likely a server thing, not a client thing.  For the `update()` script to run at the same time as the `calc()` script is already running, you need scripts that support that (no contention for shared resources) and an infrastructure that will actually run multiple PHP scripts at the same time.

Comment: @Darren - What does this question have to do with [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10152046/2518525)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you are using sessions, and both `calc.php` and `update.php` access session data. In order to ensure data consistency in sessions, access to session data is locked, so only one php process can access the session at a time. This means that while `calc.php` has the session, no other page access can read it.

What you will want to do is call [session_write_close()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) after `calc.php` has finished anything that might require access to the session, and before it starts its time-consuming task.

`session_write_close()` writes the current session's data and releases the lock. Once `calc.php` is no longer holding to the session, accesses from `update.php` can read it.