# JavaScript, React - sending multiple simultaneous ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, redux, axios

In my React application I have an array of parameters (some IDs, for example), which should be used as a parameters for an ajax call queue. The problem is that array might contain more than 1000 items and if I just recursively make the ajax call using the forEach loop, the browser page eventually stops responding before each of the requests are resolved.

Is there a technique/library, which could allow to send ajax requests, for example, by 5 requests at a time asynchronously, and only when those are finished, proceed the next 5?

Follow up questions:

[React - Controlling multiple Ajax Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251862/react-controlling-multiple-ajax-calls)

[React - Controlling AJAX calls made to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432553/react-controlling-ajax-calls-made-to-the-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are not constrained by es version and can use es6 then you should look into async await

```js
async function makeBatchCalls(arrayIds, length) {
    let test = arrayIds.reduce(
        (rows, key, index) => (index % length == 0 
            ? rows.push([key]) 
            : rows[rows.length - 1].push(key)
        ) && rows, 
        []
    );

    let Batchresults = [];

    //convert them to two dimensionl arrays of given length [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]]
    for (calls of test) {
       Batchresults.push(
           await Promise.all(
               calls.map((call) => fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${call}`))
           )
       );
    }

    return Promise.all(Batchresults); //wait for all batch calls to finish
}

makeBatchCalls([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],3)
```

async/await is meant for the exact scenario of awaiting async calls. basically inside the async function until await is resolved the execution is suspended. You would need to understand promises and generators before you start using them.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not worked, await didn't wait for the 5 calls to complete before firing another set.

Comment: HI could you try this snippet ?i feel for a bad gotcha basically await works only inside the main function it wont await  inner function(map function in the old code). This should work

Comment: Now I want to make a server call on completion of each of those promises.

Comment: Inside fetch.then(()=>makeservercall), but if I do this then entire await thing not works.

Comment: Does this makeserverCall require any data from fetch or it just needs to be fired after fetch?it should work ideally.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251862/react-controlling-multiple-ajax-calls

Comment: Please opine on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251862/react-controlling-multiple-ajax-calls , a followup question.

Comment: and question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256013/ a followup on followup question.

Comment: lets this further on chat?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257615/struggle-with-chaining-of-promises-in-react-application

Comment: Hi Shyam Babu, need your help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432553/react-controlling-ajax-calls-made-to-the-server

Comment: Hi i see there are multiple answers on that thread?I am not sure what help do you need?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, let's sort some things out. In JavaScript AJAX requests are asynchronous by nature. You chose to make them synchronous somewhat in you implementation.

What you need to do is have some array of requests, from which you pop results X at a time, wait for them to return, and repeat.

```
let ids = [a lot of ids here]

while (ids.length > 0) {

   let c = ids.splice(0, 5)
   let promises = []
   for (let i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      promises.push(fetch("someURL").then(function() {}))
   }
   Promise.all(promises)
}
```

Will execute 5 requests simultaneously, wait for them to complete, then fetch next portion of IDs

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was specifically checking if there is some library to help me with this. Or maybe some library like superagent or Axios can take care of this?

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal then it's called library, not "technique"

Comment: Promise.all will wait for all the 5 promises to get resolved before loop enters into the next iteration, correct?

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal Correct :)

Comment: Please opine on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251862/react-controlling-multiple-ajax-calls, a follow up question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in a project. What you need is a priority queue in order to control how many request will be performed simultaneously. I'm  using [this library](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue). Since the p-queue implementation is simple enough to understand and is not that big, I've pasted the code in the snippet below only to show you how it works in the latest lines.

```js
// IMPLEMENTATION ####################

// Port of lower_bound from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound
// Used to compute insertion index to keep queue sorted after insertion
function lowerBound(array, value, comp) {
  let first = 0;
  let count = array.length;

  while (count > 0) {
    const step = (count / 2) | 0;
    let it = first + step;

    if (comp(array[it], value) <= 0) {
      first = ++it;
      count -= step + 1;
    } else {
      count = step;
    }
  }

  return first;
}

class PriorityQueue {
  constructor() {
    this._queue = [];
  }

  enqueue(run, opts) {
    opts = Object.assign({
      priority: 0
    }, opts);

    const element = {
      priority: opts.priority,
      run
    };

    if (this.size && this._queue[this.size - 1].priority >= opts.priority) {
      this._queue.push(element);
      return;
    }

    const index = lowerBound(this._queue, element, (a, b) => b.priority - a.priority);
    this._queue.splice(index, 0, element);
  }

  dequeue() {
    return this._queue.shift().run;
  }

  get size() {
    return this._queue.length;
  }
}

class PQueue {
  constructor(opts) {
    opts = Object.assign({
      concurrency: Infinity,
      queueClass: PriorityQueue
    }, opts);

    if (opts.concurrency < 1) {
      throw new TypeError('Expected `concurrency` to be a number from 1 and up');
    }

    this.queue = new opts.queueClass(); // eslint-disable-line new-cap
    this._queueClass = opts.queueClass;
    this._pendingCount = 0;
    this._concurrency = opts.concurrency;
    this._resolveEmpty = () => {};
    this._resolveIdle = () => {};
  }

  _next() {
    this._pendingCount--;

    if (this.queue.size > 0) {
      this.queue.dequeue()();
    } else {
      this._resolveEmpty();

      if (this._pendingCount === 0) {
        this._resolveIdle();
      }
    }
  }

  add(fn, opts) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const run = () => {
        this._pendingCount++;

        fn().then(
          val => {
            resolve(val);
            this._next();
          },
          err => {
            reject(err);
            this._next();
          }
        );
      };

      if (this._pendingCount < this._concurrency) {
        run();
      } else {
        this.queue.enqueue(run, opts);
      }
    });
  }

  addAll(fns, opts) {
    return Promise.all(fns.map(fn => this.add(fn, opts)));
  }

  clear() {
    this.queue = new this._queueClass(); // eslint-disable-line new-cap
  }

  onEmpty() {
    // Instantly resolve if the queue is empty
    if (this.queue.size === 0) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const existingResolve = this._resolveEmpty;
      this._resolveEmpty = () => {
        existingResolve();
        resolve();
      };
    });
  }

  onIdle() {
    // Instantly resolve if none pending
    if (this._pendingCount === 0) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const existingResolve = this._resolveIdle;
      this._resolveIdle = () => {
        existingResolve();
        resolve();
      };
    });
  }

  get size() {
    return this.queue.size;
  }

  get pending() {
    return this._pendingCount;
  }
}


// TEST ####################


const promises = new PQueue({
  concurrency: 4
});

const makePromise = (key, time) => {
  let response = null;
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      response = `Promise ${key} resolved`;
      console.log(response);
      resolve(response);
    }, time);
  });
}

promises.add(() => makePromise('p1', 5000));
promises.add(() => makePromise('p2', 1000));
promises.add(() => makePromise('p3', 3000));
promises.add(() => makePromise('p4', 6000));
promises.add(() => makePromise('p5', 2000));
promises.add(() => makePromise('p6', 1500));
promises.add(() => makePromise('p7', 5500));
promises.add(() => makePromise('p8', 7000));

promises.onIdle().then(() => {
  console.log('Promises queue empty.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Juliobetta but this seems to be too much of a code. How is this different from shyam babu's code?

Comment: Both solve your problem... The shyam babu's solution is more direct, while the PQueue gives you another possibilities, like defining the priority of a request and events such as `onIdle` and `onEmpty`.

Comment: Please opine on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251862/react-controlling-multiple-ajax-calls, a followup question

Answer (score 0):

In these sort of cases, it is best to change in backend where you can process results for thousand inputs send them at one instead of calling from a thousand times. Another way is to use [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) I think.

You can also look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150159/multiple-ajax-calls-at-same-time) if it is applicable for you. I think these things answer your question