# async await to batch calls to server

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, promise, superagent

```
async function makeBatchCalls(arrayIds, length) {
    let test = arrayIds.reduce((rows, key, index) => (index % length == 0 
                ? rows.push([key]) 
                : rows[rows.length-1].push(key)) && rows, []);
    let Batchresults = []; //convert them to two dimensionl arrays of given length [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]]
    for (calls of test) {
            Batchresults.push(await Promise.all(calls.map((call)=>{
                fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${call}`)
                .then(() => makeservercall())
                })
            ));
    }
return Promise.all(Batchresults); //wait for all batch calls to finish
}

makeBatchCalls([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],3)
```

Code above works fine if I don't add the then call which makes a server call. Any pointer here is appreciated.

Linked request: [JavaScript, React - sending multiple simultaneous ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988142/javascript-react-sending-multiple-simultaneous-ajax-calls)

Comment: does it help returning the fetch result? `return fetch().then()`

Comment: the `calls.map` arrow function callbacck has a body but that is missing the `return` statement/keyword. therefor the calls.map is resolved to `[undefinde, undefined,...]`

Comment: Cool after adding return statement, it is working but now in statement makeBatchCalls([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],3).then((responses) => console.log(responses)), this console.log() prints [undefined, undefined ....]

Comment: does `makeservercall` return anything?

Comment: .then((response) => makeservercall(response)) and makeservercall doesn't return anything. It is doing another fetch.

Comment: well, `await Promise.all(..)` returns what in the promise chain at the end is returned. and that is from `makeservercall ` which is nothing, therefor `undefined`. What would you like for the makeBatchCalls() to return? fetched values? or only true / OK?

Comment: I want all the responses from fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${call}`) to be returned.

Comment: you could do: `fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${call}`)
                .then((fetchResult) => {makeservercall().then(() => fetchResult})
                })`

Comment: now responses contains two dimensional array [[response, respoonse, response], [response, response, response] ....]

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted when splitting them in two arrays? You can unpack them with console.log(...results)

Comment: ya actually, I unpacked them responses = [].split(...responses).

Comment: All done but fetch inside makeservercall is not making a server call. Do you see any issue why fetch inside makeservercall  wont work?

Comment: could you also add the code for the `makeservercall ` method?

Comment: it worked, thanks for all the help here (y)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154258/discussion-between-lokesh-agrawal-and-user2520818).