# React - Controlling AJAX calls made to the server

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, promise, async.js

In my React application I have an array of parameters (some IDs, for example), which should be used as a parameters for an ajax call queue. The problem is that array might contain more than 1000 items and if I just recursively make the ajax call using the forEach loop, the browser page eventually stops responding before each of the requests are resolved.

Is there a library, which could allow to send ajax requests, for example, maintaining 5 requests at a time asynchronously.

This is the code which I am using for now.

```
async function makeBatchCalls(arrayIds, length) 
{
     //convert arrayIds to two dimensional arrays of given length [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10] ....]
     let test = arrayIds.reduce(
             (rows, key, index) => (index % length == 0 
                                    ? rows.push([key]) 
                                    : rows[rows.length-1].push(key)) && rows, []);

    let Batchresults = [];

    for (calls of test) {
        Batchresults.push(await Promise.all(calls.map((call)=>fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${call}`))));
    }
return Promise.all(Batchresults); //wait for all batch calls to finish
}

makeBatchCalls([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],5)
```

Problem with this code is it waits for 5 calls to complete and then send another batch of 5 calls. This is not an effective utilisation of the network. What I want is at any point of time there should be 5 requests.

Is it possible to tweak above code itself to cater the requirements?

Comment: Could you refactor your `reduce` statement to use more than one line and maybe not the ternary operator ? I am having trouble understanding what you want to do with it.

Comment: Done, please check now.

Comment: I provided an answer, hope it helps. Please find the time to look at the answers and check the one you think fits the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interesting problem to solve. One approach I can think is to make the `6th` ajax call as soon as any one in first batch finishes. This way there will be 5 ajax requests in process at any moment. I have tried to implement something similar. Though my solution does not make ajax calls, but I am guessing you can changed the `process` function to make the ajax call and return the promise back.

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/zamotus/edit?js,console)

```js
/** 
  This function processes the jobs in batches, once a job is finished in batch it   then processes the next job. This can be used to make network calls.  
*/
function processBatch(queue, batchSize, processJob) {
  // remove a batch of items from the queue
  const items = queue.splice(0, batchSize);
  let count = items.length;

  // no more items?
  if (!count) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return items.forEach((item, i) => {
      return processJob(item).then(result => {
        return processBatch(queue, 1, processJob)
          .then(_ => --count || resolve());
      });
    });
  })
}

// create queue
var queue = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  queue.push(i);
}

// a per-item action
function process(item) {
  console.log('starting ' + item + '...');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // (simulating ajax)
    return setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('completed ' + item + '!');
      resolve();
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
  });
}

// start processing queue!
processBatch(queue, 5, process)
  .then(result => console.log("All jobs processed"));
```

I just tried to implement a generic function using promises. You can try to run same with ajax calls. I would be interested to know how this solution would work for you.

As you can see, I am recursively calling the `processBatch` function after successful execution of each job and the successive `batchSize` is hard coded to `1`, but that can be changed and parameterized. Also, this function will work for only happy path case, as it does not take rejected promises into consideration.

Comment: this looks promising (haha), I was actually looking to make a promise queue for an upcoming change to our project. Definitely going to give this solution a try

Comment: Thanks @clurect. Let me know how it works out for you.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, I am going to propose a different solution than the one you proposed, this one will make sure that there is always 5 requests being processed at maximum at each time.

```
function makeBatchCalls(arrayIds, length) {
    // determines how many queries are being sent at any given time
    let queued = 0;
    // determines the index of the query to send at any given time
    let currentIndex = 0;
    // recursive function that launches queries and makes sure the queue is respected
    let launchNext = function() {
        if (queued === length) {
            return;
        }
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${arrayIds[currentIndex]}`).then((results) => {
            queued--;
            launchNext();
            // do something with your results here...
        });
        queued++;
        currentIndex++;
    };
    // launch the first length queries as the queue is empty at first
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        launchNext();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue) library for your use case. There is a queue function that does exactly this. It maintains a queue of tasks to be executed and executes them maintaining desired concurrency at all times.

Here is how your function can be changed to use Async queue.

```
async function makeBatchCalls(arrayIds, length) 
{
    // create a queue object with concurrency 5(equal to batch length in your case)
    var q = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
        //Call your api for this task here
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${call}`)
        .then(function (response) {
            //Once your task executes successfully, call the Q callback so that next pending task can be picked up. 
            //This ensures all your tasks keep running one after the other with desired concurrency
            callback();
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            //in case of failure, either you can return, or you can move to next task by calling callback
        });
    }, 5);

    // Is called when all the tasks have completed
    q.drain = function() {
        console.log('all items have been processed');
    };

    // push all items to queue
    for(var i=0; i < arrayIds.length; i++){
        q.push(arrayIds[i]);
    }
}

makeBatchCalls([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],5)
```